# Closed xml error: "Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part" Apostrophe issue

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

While dynamically creating Excel workbooks in C# using Closed XML, I encountered an error in Excel when attempting to open the workbook. The issue was caused by an apostrophe (') in the name of a sheet. When Excel "repairs" and opens the workbook, the sheet's name remains unchanged and is still there with the offending apostrophe...

Excel does support apostrophes in the sheet name.

ExcelSheets with Apostrophes:

[image]

Why does it choke on this character when being generated with Closed XML?

I can easily remove this as a "special character" but would prefer not to.

This is related to: [xlsx error: "Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part" when tried to resolve errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539267/xlsx-error-removed-records-named-range-from-xl-workbook-xml-part-when-tried/18540714#18540714) i

Comment: Have you tried escaping the apostrophe (`\'`) ?

Answer (score 0):

This may well be to do with the name of a named range, not the name of a sheet. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539267/xlsx-error-removed-records-named-range-from-xl-workbook-xml-part-when-tried/44416204#44416204)