# Power Query / Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a file with power query fetching data from different sources and then basis the data I have created pivots and dashboards. I have never faced this issue before but recently when I shared the file within my team the file showed this error "**Removed Part: /xl/queryTables/queryTable2.xml part. (External data range)**.

Although the things are working fine, but how to avoid this error or rectify this.

TIA.

Comment: Please post more detail. What is your data source? etc.

Comment: Data source is xlxs file.The idea is every time i need to refresh the data with latest numbers, I open query editor and "Change Data Source" this leads to source data refresh, pivot refresh and excel dashboard data refresh without much manual work. Hope this us clear! Also if any suggestion around automate the data change part too without manually doing it would be helpful.

Comment: Not your question, but instead of having to change your queries, make a new tab, table, and query called "Config" with "Name" and "Value" columns, then make a "ConfigRecord" query which is just `Record.FromTable(Config)`. Then, if you have a row in your Config table with a Name of "SourceFilePath”, you can change your hardcoded file path to `ConfigRecord[SourceFilePath]` and then all you need to do is edit the file path within the Config tab and click Data - Refresh All.

Comment: Better yet, make a separate query called "SourceFilePath" with code of `ConfigRecord[SourceFilePath]`, and then if you can figure out a better way to derive the file path you have one compartmentalized place to alter it.

Comment: Wait... When you share it with your team, are all of your dependent files readable by each user under the same file path??

Comment: Some good troubleshooting steps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539267/xlsx-error-removed-records-named-range-from-xl-workbook-xml-part-when-tried